# Music player without files

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.1-jelly-bean, music-player, media-scanner

My music player suddenly stopped and it says there are no songs.

But in fact, there are songs in my SD-Card.

I had a similar problem that is the gallery didn't display images and also I have deleted a `nomedia .txt` file in internal folder to fix it.

Any suggestions? I'm using samsung galaxy s3 mini which runs on android 4.1.2

Comment: Your files is in which folder? @Santropedro

Comment: It's in storage/sdcard0/Music

Comment: try this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83860/mp3-not-showing-in-library